# How to preprocess output of any CLI Tool in realtime?

Tags: text-formatting, nix

For context, what I am trying to do is add a preprocessor to a REPL, more specifically, `nix repl`. Although this would probably apply to any other REPL like application.

The reason for it is that I want to add a formatting step to its output, eg:

```
$ nix repl
Welcome to Nix 2.17.1. Type :? for help.

nix-repl> ↵

nix-repl> { a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; } ↵
{ a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; }
```

```
$ nix repl
Welcome to Nix 2.17.1. Type :? for help.

nix-repl> ↵

nix-repl> { a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; } ↵
{ 
  a = 1; 
  b = 2; 
  c = 3; 
}
```

Out of the REPL, I can do this via `nixfmt < <(echo "{ a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; }")`, so my idea was that, if I could somehow preprocess all outputs of the REPL in real-time, I could conditionally apply the formatting...

I have tried using `unbuffer`, `stdbuf`, `socat`, piping in multiple different ways, but in all of my attempts, either STDIN disappears until the next command is run, nothing is shown at all, or TAB completion breaks. And because there are so many different answers, I don't know which to really go down into. Maybe I am just using these tools wrong, maybe these aren't even the right tools, or maybe this is not possible without actually modifying the REPL binary. I would greatly appreciate just being pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I tried `nixfmt | nix repl` and `nixfmt | nix repl --file -`, but no go. I'd really love to see if this is possible.

Comment: @l0b0 I was not able to figure it out using shell output redirection, but I managed to get this feature working on a [hacky fork](https://github.com/MathiasSven/nix-pretty-repl) of `nix` which calls `nixfmt` directly, I will be using as my new repl command.

Comment: Nice! You should probably submit that upstream.

Comment: Many cli tools (especially when they use the C FILE interface) buffer output data when stdout is not connected to a terminal (vs.pipe, file...). But you can try to wrap nix in a pseudo terminal: socat - EXEC:"nix repl",pty,cfmakeraw

Comment: Note that as of Nix 2.21, Nix can be configured to pretty-print values in the REPL. https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/release-notes/rl-2.21.html https://github.com/NixOS/nix/pull/9931

Answer (score 1):

`nix repl` does not appear to implement a way to do this. All repl output goes to stdout.

You'd either have to build a program that post-processes `nix repl` output from stdout such that everything between the lines starting with `nix-repl>` markers is passed to `nixfmt` or build this into Nix' repl code itself.

Given how hacky the former is, the latter would probably be preferable.